# issues abour shaders and transformations in opengl

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, transformation

- If I'm not wrong, shaders are programs that run in GPU, right?
- Do we send data to this programs using glUniformMatrix*?
- I don't know if it's right but if I send a MVP matrix to the shader, the object's vertices that I want to render will use the position calculated by the shader right before calling the render function.
- If I want to render a lot of objects and I must send the MVP matrix then render the object right after, so I will have a code that send to GPU -> render a lot of times. However if I'm not wrong again this is not a good practice because I'm losing performance because the cost of send information to GPU is very expensive. So a way to get a better performance is send all the informations to GPU then render all the objects.
- And the questions of 1 million dollars is, How can the shader program identify that the MVP matrix is used by a single object and not another one?

Comment: Sending matrices to the GPU is cheap. What is not cheap is transforming vertices on the CPU and then uploading them to the GPU or worse yet constantly loading new texture data. Those are the things you should focus on minimizing, and if you want to minimize the overhead of uniform data transfer you should consider `Uniform Buffer Objects`. If used correctly, you can share the same matrices between multiple GLSL programs and can upload multiple uniform variables in a single call with UBOs.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, I'm calculating the MVp on cpu beacause I'm doing a hierarchical transformation, my problem is that I need to render 64 models of a hand that is made by 30 objects like spheres and cylinders.

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like skeletal animation. The common approach there is to use a uniform buffer object. A lot of people start out with an array of matrix uniforms only to find out that they run out of uniform storage space rather quickly. UBOs also overcome the default implementation-specific limitation of 1024 floating-point uniform components per-stage (each `mat4` takes 16 floating-point components). Because uniform storage space is shared between constants and other uniforms, you can quickly run out of space if you do not use UBOs.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman okay, witch uniform blocks I can send to GPU all the matrices of a set of objects, but can I send a set of sets of objects like a vector of uniform blocks?

Comment: Yes, declare it as an array and then use a contiguous block of those uniforms. You should investigate the `std140` layout qualifier rules, because to do this properly you need to account for alignment. GL implementations will pad your data structure for correct alignment using a well-defined set of rules if you use `std140`, if you do not, then you will have to query the offset of each element in the uniform block (implementations are free to align things any way they see fit if you do not request `std140`) and that is a royal pain in the butt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I'm not wrong, shaders are programs that run in GPU, right?

Possibly. Many implementations of OpenGL have software renderers that they can fall back to if resources on the GPU are constrained. But usually, yes, they're run on the GPU.

> Do we send data to this programs using `glUniformMatrix*`?

That's the usual way. You also set things like texture coordinates either via immediate mode methods like `glTexCoord*()` (in legacy OpenGL), or via buffer objects.

> I don't know if it's right but if I send a MVP matrix to the shader, the object's vertices that I want to render will use the position calculated by the shader right before calling the render function.

There are different types of shaders. A vertex shader is called once for each vertex. A fragment shader is called once per fragment (roughly once per output screen-space pixel that actually gets drawn). Generally you will probably want to send the model, view, and projection matrices separately to the vertex shader. (Or possibly in some combination that lifts some computations out of the shader.) Then you'll multiply each vertex by the appropriate matrix (or combo of matrices).

And there are other types of shaders beyond those, but those 2 are the most common.

> If I want to render a lot of objects and I must send the MVP matrix then render the object right after, so I will have a code that send to GPU -> render a lot of times. However if I'm not wrong again this is not a good practice because I'm losing performance because the cost of send information to GPU is very expensive. So a way to get a better performance is send all the informations to GPU then render all the objects.

I wouldn't get overly worried about performance until you have shaders working properly. Performance can be dependent on a lot of different factors. One is how often you send or receive data to or from the GPU and how much data you're transferring. Another is how many passes you do for each shader, and another is the size of your textures, geometry, and other stuff.

> And the questions of 1 million dollars is, How can the shader program identify that the MVP matrix is used by a single object and not another one?

The way I've done that in the past is to set the current shader program and uniforms via `glUseProgram()` and `glUniform*()`, then upload my geometry for an object, and repeat as necessary for each object or set of objects as needed.